# DFA construction - How to construct an automaton that contains either 0 or 1 occurrences of 010?

Tags: automata

I can't seem to make it work. I think I managed to produce a solution when it's exactly one occurrence of 010 but not when it's *at most* one occurrence. [Check out my automaton.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At9t8.png)

Comment: Would $01010$ contain two occurrences of $010$?

Comment: One occurrence.

Comment: Please mention then "two disjoint occurences" or so. The question should please be also a part of the posted question, not only the title.

Comment: Making A,B,C,D,E,F final, but not G is the solution?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following states:

- $A$: initial
- $B$: have not seen $010$ yet, just saw $0$
- $C$: have not seen $010$ yet, just saw $01$
- $D$: have seen $010$ already
- $E$: have seen $010$ already, just saw $0$
- $F$: have seen $010$ already, just saw $01$

with transitions $A\stackrel 0\to B$, $A\stackrel 1\to A$, $B\stackrel 0\to B$, $B\stackrel 1\to C$, $C\stackrel 0\to E$, $C\stackrel 1\to A$, $D\stackrel 0\to E$, $D\stackrel 1\to D$, $E\stackrel 0\to E$, $E\stackrel 1\to F$, $F\stackrel 0\to $☠, $F\stackrel 1\to D$ and all states (except ☠) accepting.

(According to the comment added that $01010$ should only count one occurance of $010$, we need the transition $C\stackrel 0\to D$ instead of $C\stackrel 0\to E$)

Comment: I'm always a bit conflicted in cases like this. From an educational perspective I believe your answer would actually be better without giving the transitions and letting the asker figure it out for themselves. From a knowledge base perspective your answer right now is better...